# Design editor is unavailable until a successful build...This error is showing in my android studio activity_main.xml

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Here's the image which shows many errors.please someone fix this as I am new to android developement.

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL8Bc.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL8Bc.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4piOG.jpg)

Comment: please share your xml code

Comment: to show you xl file design in android studio design first u have to build you project successfully. that may bi an issue with you project. so make a build first.